# run streamlit app using Network URL not working

Tags: python, webserver, streamlit, offlineapps

I have streamlit app that i try to run on my localhost and work fine but when i try to use the `NETWORK URL` on other computer it did not work and just display white blank page like below :
[image]

**PS:** All the computers are offline they are not connected to the internet. they are all on the same network and they can connect to each other where they have some sharing files.

**However if i run the app on a pc that is online and try to enter from another pc it works.**

- Operating system: windows 7
- python version:3.7
- streamlit version: 1.8

My question is do i need to run the app on a web server or just if i run it from my computer others can use the app ??
like do i need to run the app on a windows server or i need to install an apache webserver like **wamp**? or just it can be done from my pc without any of these??

Comment: although you are using same network for all the system, you have to connect (SSH) to the server where you are running this application.